# Get-PnPUnifiedAuditLog using error

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell, audit-log-reports

When i try to get microsoft 365 audit log with pnp powershell, it reports

```
 Get-PnPUnifiedAuditLog : Trying to get a token for a different endpoint while being connected through an ACS token is
     not possible. Please connect differently.
```

Firstly, I created a app with ActivityFeed.Read permissions to get unified audit logs from the Office 365 Management API in aad,
Then I use the following code:

```
 Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -ClientId e68b50b6-ef63-4396-acc9-97260482000a -ClientSecret 8oh8Q~ooooP3sE2qSJpWOWlxE9o9o9_S4X~NdaPl
 Get-PnPUnifiedAuditLog -ContentType SharePoint -StartTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-2) -EndTime (Get-Date).AddDays(-1)
```

[image]

Screenshot of the same app information request Office 365 Management API：
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you confirm if you have followed the same steps as given here: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/288436/how-to-use-get-pnpunifiedauditlog-command?

Comment: Yes, i can get the access token with the same application id and secret when i call the Office 365 Management API directly.

Comment: @GaneshSanap I have updated my original post.